# Get all reachable IP addresses within a private network

Tags: ipv4, network, ipv6, network-discovery

Is there a way to get all reachable IP addresses within a private network. I know that we can get all active devices' IP addresses within same subnet using arp.
I was wondering if something similar exists for entire private network

Comment: Is this what you're after - https://serverfault.com/questions/1137038/find-lans-ipv6-multicast-address-or-else-all-currently-responsive-lan-members

Answer (score 1):

There's no really reliable way.

Generally, you'd need a request-response type protocol that is implemented (or mandatory) on all hosts. While ARP is a protocol that *must* work for IPv4 to function, there's nothing mandatory for IPv4 itself. ARP isn't routable, and for routed subnets you need something routable.

- ICMP *echo* (`ping`) is often suppressed by the host firewall, or ICMP generally in a network (bad idea but common)
- relying on ICMP *Destination unreachable* messages from the connecting router/gateway (due to failing ARP) may not work when those messages are rate-limited or suppressed completely, obstructing rapid sweeps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Zac67 !! My use case is that I want to know all the machines which are running my spring application, I want to hit an endpoint on all those machines and reply with a small response. Do you think there is some way to achieve this ?

Comment: If it's your application, you can add a discovery method, e.g. a UDP listener that replies with some (indiscriminate) identification. Note that applications and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hey @Zac67 I understand that that this question is off topic for this stackexchange do you know a forum where I can get some help for this

Comment: If it's about programming, [so] comes to mind.

Comment: I tried that but it was closed there as well :(

Comment: @AtharwaAdawdakar, an application you create could subscribe to a specific multicast group, and when a message is sent to the group, all could reply to the origin of the multicast. To get all hosts on a particular internetwork, you could implement multicast routing, which is very different than the normal unicast routing. This will not work on the public Internet, and you would need to implement some type of "phone home" for that, but that could be blocked by network administrators. In any case, this is not network engineering.